Representation of smooth 1-forms with smooth vector fields on Riemannian manifolds
I'm interested to prove the following result:

Let $(M, g)$ be a Riemannian manifold, let $\omega \in \Omega^1(M)$
Then $\exists! V \in \mathfrak{X}(M)$ such that $g(V, X)=\omega(X), \forall X \in \mathfrak{X}(M)$

My attempt is the following:
Step1:[Unicity]: Let assume the exististence then the unicity follow trivially by the non degeneracy of the metric.
Step2:[Existence]: It is sufficient to prove the existence in the case in which the support of $\omega$ is contained in a single chart, indeed in the general case will be sufficient to use the existence on every chart together with the unicity of step1 to conclude the statement.
Let $(U, x^1, .., x^n)$ be the coordinate chart of M, let $(X_i)$ be the coordinate frame and $(dx^i)$ be the dual coframe. Let V some (a priori) rought vector field with values on $TM\big{|}_U$ defined by $V = V^iX_i$, locally on $U$ we can write:
$$\omega = \omega_i dx^i$$
$$g(V, .) = V^ig(X_i, X_j)dx^j$$
Then $\omega=g(V, .)$ iff $\omega_j = V^ig(X_i, X_j), \forall j=1, .. ,n$, then using the cramer rule we obtain explicitly:
$$V^i = \frac{\begin{vmatrix}
        g_{11} & .. & g_{(i-1)1} & \omega_1 & g_{(i+1)1} & g_{n1}  \\
        . & . & . & . & . & . \\  
        . & . & . & . & . & . \\  
        . & . & . & . & . & . \\  
        g_{1n} & .. & g_{(i-1)n} & \omega_1 & g_{(i+1)n} & g_{nn}  \\
      \end{vmatrix}}{\begin{vmatrix}
        g_{ij} \\
      \end{vmatrix}}, \forall i=1, .. ,n$$
Since $[g_{ij}]$ is positive-definite and $C^{\infty}(M; \mathbb{R})$ is a module, we have that $V^i \in C^{\infty}(M; \mathbb{R}), \forall i$, then $V \in \mathfrak{X}(U)$. $\square$

At any point $p\in M$, there is unique $V_p$ such that $g(V_p, X_p)= \omega_p(X_p)$ for any $X_p\in T_pM$ by linear algebra,  where $\omega_p$ is the restriction of $\omega$ at $p$.    Then, from the  pointwise $V_p$, we have a unique $V \in \mathfrak{X}(M)$ satisfy it.
